# SQLite query in populated table not returning anything?

Tags: database, sqlite

I have created a db called AllWords.db in sqlite that contains a list of all english words (count:172820). When I issue a select all query, it returns a list of all 172820 words. Also, when I print the count of the table words like this :

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM words;
```

the output is 172820, so the database clearly has all the words included in it. However, when I try to check if a word exists (the only thing I'll want to do with this database), it doesn't print anything :

```
SELECT * FROM words WHERE word="stuff";
```

returns nothing.

The database is a single table with the only column being 'words', which has all the words as rows. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: And I take it you're sure that "stuff" is a word in the database?

Comment: Is the column named `word` or `words`?

Comment: If the answer to my question is yes, then see if a [SELECT * FROM words WHERE word LIKE '%stuff%'] returns anything.

Comment: I'm sure that 'stuff' is in there, as it's in the output when I select all from words. When I try the like operator it returns a bunch of words that have 'stuff' in it, including 'stuff' itself. Could trailing or leading white space be affecting it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question because I figured out what was wrong. To populate the table, I had written a python program to parse a file called words.txt (all words, separated by newlines), into sqlite. My problem was the query turned into :

```
INSERT INTO WORDS VALUES('englishWord\n')
```

And that messed up the database. I fixed that and it started to work, thanks to @ScoPi for the hint with using LIKE, it helped me figure out that there was a stray newline character.

Answer (score 1):

Just to be sure you use a word in your database, look into your table with

```
select * from words limit 10
```

> house
>   stuff
>   tree
>   ...

and then select with one of the words you see

```
select * from words where word = 'stuff'
```

**Edit**: fixed where clause according to @MichaelEakins

**Edit2**: Unfortunately there's no difference between single and double quotes in this case, see [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!5/48e4c/4/0)